# ERROR: checking the archiver (false) interface... unknown

Tags: linux, make, configure, pcre

While I was installing `pcre2-10.21` on Solars 10 (`SunOS 5.10 Generic_147440-01 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise`) the `./configure` command led to the above error.

```
checking the archiver (false) interface... unknown  
configure: error: could not determine false interface
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `./configure` can not find the `ar` archiver in the path.

So we can add it using:

```
export PATH=/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/usr/sfw/sbin:$PATH
```